# How to lazy-load an html template in yui3?

Tags: javascript, yui, lazy-loading, yui3

How can I lazy-load html templates in yui3? Looking at the examples, the preferred way for loading templates seems to be to embed them in a script element in the html, like in this example:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-todo.html

I tried putting my template in its own html file and then lazy-loading it with the Get class, but that really loads the content as a script, which obviously doesn't work.

So, is IO Utility the way to go? It seems like a complicated way to do something simple like loading a chunk of html. If that is the best way to do it, can anyone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Try node.load(urlToFetchTemplate); where the server returns the <script> tag with id and template markup inside.

Comment: I could probably make that work by loading the template into a hidden div. However, I was hoping to find a way to load it directly into a variable. I've got something more-or-less working with Y.io, but I was hoping this was a common issue and there would be a widely accepted standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to explore YUI.io for this. But for now, I came up with a work around (ugly solution) is to wrap the whole template content with javascript method. The file gets executed in browser when it gets downloaded as javacript by YUI3 loader.

```
Template File :  mypopup.js 

writeTemplate(' <-- my whole template content goes here with js escaped-->');

== and here is the function to write the template to hidden placeholder on the page ===

window.writeTemplate = function(txt) {
    document.getElementById('templateHolder').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Please update this thread if you find a cleaner way of doing this.